# C file open() function is only setting user level permission in Android

Tags: android, c, file-io, fopen, android-sdcard

I am using C open() function to create the file in android and set the access permission as required. I am observing that in Android, the open() is only able to set the user level access permission. To give the file necessary group & other level permission I have to explicitly use chmod() after creating the file.

Here is what I am doing,

```
/*Test code - starts*/
    tmp = open("/data/data/com.application.app1.tests/foo5.txt", O_CREAT | O_RDWR | O_TRUNC | O_SYNC, S_IRUSR | S_IWUSR | S_IRGRP | S_IWGRP ); // these permissions doen't seems o work hence will work with chmod
    close(tmp);
    tmp = open("/data/data/com.application.app1.tests/foo7.txt", O_CREAT | O_RDWR | O_TRUNC | O_SYNC, S_IRUSR | S_IWUSR | S_IRGRP | S_IWGRP | S_IROTH | S_IWOTH);
    close(tmp);
    tmp = open("/data/data/com.application.app1.tests/foo8.txt", O_CREAT | O_RDONLY, S_IRUSR | S_IRGRP | S_IROTH);
    close(tmp);

    tmp = open("/data/data/com.application.app1.tests/foo55.txt", O_CREAT | O_RDWR | O_TRUNC | O_SYNC, S_IRUSR | S_IWUSR | S_IRGRP | S_IWGRP); // these permissions doen't seems o work hence will work with chmod
    close(tmp);
    chmod("/data/data/com.application.app1.tests/foo55.txt", S_IRUSR | S_IWUSR | S_IRGRP | S_IWGRP);
    tmp = open("/data/data/com.microsoft.palAWasp.tests/foo77.txt", O_CREAT | O_RDWR | O_TRUNC | O_SYNC, S_IRUSR | S_IWUSR | S_IRGRP | S_IWGRP | S_IROTH | S_IWOTH);
    close(tmp);
    chmod("/data/data/com.application.palAWasp.tests/foo77.txt", S_IRUSR | S_IWUSR | S_IRGRP | S_IWGRP | S_IROTH | S_IWOTH);
    tmp = open("/data/data/com.application.app1.tests/foo88.txt", O_CREAT | O_RDONLY, S_IRUSR | S_IRGRP | S_IROTH);
    close(tmp);
    chmod("/data/data/com.application.app1.tests/foo88.txt", S_IRUSR | S_IRGRP | S_IROTH);

    /*Test code - Ends*/
```

The output of the following is something like this,

[image]

/***************EDIT***************/
Another important observation is that when I tried creating the similar files with the above-mentioned permission bits then the default permission bits are,

```
-rw------- u0_a100  u0_a100         0 2018-03-26 12:43 foo5.txt
-rw------- u0_a100  u0_a100         0 2018-03-26 12:43 log0.log
```

and when I try to change the permission bits using chmod it is failing.
Please note that chmod is working for files in data directory but not for files on /sdcard/

Please help me in understanding this behavior.

Comment: About the fact that chmod is working in data directory but not for files on /sdcard, maybe it is related with the fact that the partition mounted into /sdcard is different from the data directory. Maybe I am mistake, but I guess /sdcard use fat32? please correct me if I am mistake.

Answer (score 4):

Probably what you are looking for is set the umask so that the default permissions are assigned as you expect.

[Linux umask command](https://www.computerhope.com/unix/uumask.htm)

This other link explain how it works. Note the area related with error codes and its explanation.

[Setting Permissions](https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Setting-Permissions.html)

In overview: The system restrict the permissions of a file when it is created based into the umask associated to the process. You can change later the permissions using chmod or fchmod. If the filesystem does not allow some permissions (for example try to set write permissions to a file that is hosted into a read-only filesystem), you will receive an error. This could apply too, if some options when the filesystem is mounted were specified. This could explain the fact that your chmod invoked on the /data is working and not into /sdcard (different filesystems with different umask options associated to them). To know more about your scenario, check errno when the chmod function fail.

In other words:

final_mask = mask_open & ~umask_process & mask_opt_filesystem

where mask_open are the permissions specified into the "open()" function; umask_process is the permissions specified into the umask associated to the process; mask_opt_filesystem are the mask associated to the filesystem that is combined with the above when creating a new file; final_mask is the final mask that represent the permissions to be assigned to the just created file.

Finally, you can change the umask for the current process, and subprocesses, but it is not recommendable, based into the read of the above links, so that, you are doing the right thing with chmod.

If you run "mount" into a terminal inside your Android device, you can see some entries appear the option "mode". This is the mask used for that filesystem. If you run "umask" into the same terminal, you can see the umask applied into the terminal.

Comment: so you meant this is not any android behavour for /sdcard/ or any other location?

Comment: Please reply. I do not understand what you meant by this.

Comment: In regarding to the umask, it changes the permissions for every file created whatever is the location. Beyond the above sentence, probably different filesystem set different restrictions, because of that you are getting different behavior for /sdcard and other locations. FAT32 does not support permissions by group,user,others. I think you can change the default by changing the mount options. This would affect all the system, and all applications. Let me know if this clarify your doubts. If not, please be more concrete.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. How can I check whether this umask permission is set or not?

Comment: As Android is based on Linux, maybe you can find a file in /etc/fstab with information about the mount options for /sdcard (see mount man page for more information about the details for the options into a specific filesystem, and the default values). As Linux is so flexible, maybe is using other way. Let me deploy an Android into a VM and I will take a look to it. In regarding to the umask, if you open a terminal to your Android device or virtual device, probably executing the command "umask" you can see the current mask used. Have a look to the man page could clarify more. Hope this help.

Comment: Thank again. umask says 000 and that means all the permissions are allowed.

Answer (score 3):

Absolutely agree with @Alejandro that you need to change process's permission mask with [`umask()`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/umask.2.html) to achieve what you want.

But need to stress that it is risky since whole Android framework relies on the fact that mask has some predefined value and won't be changed during process lifetime. System libraries may create some temporary or internal stuff and it would be wise to not break existing permission mask. Even temporary change-restore is not safe regarding that we are in multithreaded environment.

At the end manual `chmod()` looks the safest way for you.